# rails activerecord swap data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to make 1 product in the top of the list. I tryed:

```
  @allProd = Product.where(service_id:params[:id], product_category_id:descenId).order(rating: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
  tmp = @allProd[0]
  indx = @allProd.find_index(Product.find(prodId))
  @allProd[0] = @allProd[indx]
  @allProd[indx] = tmp
```

But array of datas are not changed. What is the best way to do this?

UPD:
Final solution was

```
 @allProd = Product.where(service_id:params[:id], product_category_id:descenId).order(rating: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8).to_a
   @allProd.delete(Product.find(prodId))
   @allProd = @allProd.unshift(Product.find(prodId))
```

But keep in mind that you will have problems with number of paginated products if shifted product is in not first page. But for me, it is ok)

Comment: The problem, that I see here is that paginate won't work here. And I am sorry, but I am interested, why do you need to swap elements? If you want to make some Product at the top - that is another case.

Comment: @arthur.karganyan, why pagination won't work? It works perfectly. Yes, I need to make product at the top. I have no idea except swaping, how it can be achieved?

Comment: It won't work because pagination is applied only to ActiveRecord::Relation. This solution has bugs with pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure that this is what you are trying to achieve, but can try

```
@allProd = Product.where(service_id:params[:id], product_category_id:descenId).order(rating: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8).to_a.unshift(Product.find(prodId))
```

I assume that on each page Product with id prodId will be the first.

Comment: problems with pagination, there are 9 product in first page=(, not 8

Comment: Finally, the solution was just to delete good befote adding. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I am also interested, why do you need to swap elements? If you only make 1 product in the top of the list then use "unshift" function.

```
 @allProd=[[]]
 @allProd = Product.where(service_id:params[:id], product_category_id:descenId).order(rating: :desc)
 @allProd=@allProd.unshift(name_of_product_obj_you_want_to_add_at_top)
```

And then apply pagination to "@allProd" array.